# Google Drive API does not upload a file

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have created API accent and used the following code, when I run this in a web browser, it asks me to authorise the App, which I do, and then no file is created in google drive. Instead the browser redirects to my callback. What am I doing wrong?

```
   require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
   require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

   $client = new Google_Client();
   // Get your credentials from the console
   $client->setClientId('myid');
   $client->setClientSecret('mysecret');
   $client->setRedirectUri('http://mydomain.com/oauth2callback');
   $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

   $service = new Google_DriveService($client);

   $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

   //Request authorization


   // Exchange authorization code for access token
   $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
   $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  //Insert a file
   $file = new Google_DriveFile();
   $file->setTitle('My document');
   $file->setDescription('A test document');
   $file->setMimeType('text/plain');

   $data = "Hello World";

   $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
  'data' => $data,
  'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
));

   print_r($createdFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to enter the authentication code in $authCode
Insert this code :

```
$authcode = 'xxxxxxxxxx' // insert your authentication code that you get from your browser
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
```